# Failed to compute assembly metadata hash

Tags: moles

Moles seem to choke when I try to mollify a certain DLL. It exits with the error code -1 and the messages would say:

```
cache: failed to compute assembly metadata hash
code: failed to generate stub type for ... (a bunch of this)
```

Also, setting Diagnostic=true and Verbosity=Noisy only seem to work if we have 1 .moles file. If we have more than 1 DLL to mole / multiple .moles files, we still get a somewhat 'summarized' output view - which will not expose any errors / warnings during the generation of moled DLLS - causing us to wonder what went wrong.

Finally, the DLL can be consumed consumed by the actual application code without any visible issues, except when putting it through Moles.

I can accept if the DLL is somewhat faulty, but what could be the reason behind these messages when the symptoms only exist in Moles?

I am using the latest version of Moles ( v0.94.51023.0).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes this, but to fix it I usually have to remove both the Moles AND the original assembly reference before re-adding and re-building.